# Remove number in xml tag

Tags: php, python, xml, json, string

Hullo,
I am trying to parse data from a python script directly connected to a a server back-office in php. To do that I converted the received array to JSON and then, in a php script, I converted it into XML so to parse it on another server with file_get_html. All good and fine but for a tag issue. Basically the tags are numbered as in

```
<item0></item0><item1></item1>...
```

and if I use

```
foreach($html->find('item') as $element)
```

I find nothing.

Is there a way to either parse all the tags starting with *item* OR at least transform all the string of the kind  into  (even that would of course slow the processing, but anyway..) OR appropriately change all the relevant string names either in php or python in the various phases?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

First do not load XML as HTML. This can destroy it.

It is possible to fetch all tags that start with an defined string.

```
$xml =  <<<'XML'
<items>
  <item0></item0>
  <item1></item1>
</items>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//*[starts-with(local-name(), "item")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump($node->getNodePath());
}
```

But why do you number the tags? You are aware that XML allows you to have siblings with the same element name?

```
<items>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
  ...
</items>
```

The Xpath for this structure would be `/items/item`.

Or if you like to keep an array from JSON grouped in XML use a simple name like _ for child elements:

```
{ 
  "title" : "foo",
  "items" : [ 1 , 2, 3 ]
}

<json>
  <title>foo</title>
  <items>
    <_>1</_>
    <_>2</_>
    <_>3</_>
  </items>
</json>
```

The Xpath for this structure would be `/json/items/*` or for a specific item `/json/items/*[2]`.

Comment: As a matter of fact I would like to parse it with file_get_html to build a new XML with some changed tags. From what you wrote it seams that in $node->getNodePath() I get the content inside the various itemn tags, and that would be what I am looking for. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work: as you may see at:
http://www.miafoto.it/iPhone/inarrivo/php/OO/backRomeTable.php?palina=00043 the result is empty, while if you call the urls been displayed you have the correct source xml to parse.
Of course I am not sure if the item tag should be the first string, as it is not presently the case. I will also test that.

Comment: Now it is cleaner but the item tags are a bit embedded as in:
<palina><request><risposta><nome>PARTIGIANI (FS)</nome><collocazione>PLE DEI PARTIGIANI, 20 M. CIRCA PRIMA CIV. 33 CORSIA SX LATO PARCHEGGIO AREA BUS - CAPOLINEA 121</collocazione><primi_per_palina><item0><nome_palina>PARTIGIANI (FS)</nome_palina><id_palina>00043</id_palina><arrivi><item0><non_monitorata>1</non_monitorata><nome_palina>PARTIGIANI (FS)</nome_palina><meb/><aria/><moby/><id_palina>00043</id_palina><pedana/><linea>121</linea></item0></arrivi></item0></primi_per_palina><arrivi/></risposta></request></palina>

Comment: Perhaps it would be even easier to get the values in the dictionary, even if the values are somewhat nested: I will try that.
array(2) { ... ["arrivi"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["non_monitorata"]=> bool(true) ["nome_palina"]=> string(15) ".." ["meb"]=> bool(false) ["aria"]=> bool(false) ["moby"]=> bool(false) ["id_palina"]=> string(5) "00043" ["pedana"]=> bool(false) ["linea"]=> string(3) "121" } } } } ["arrivi"]=> array(0) { } } }

Comment: If you load xml as html, it will remove the namespaces, and can change other things (add html and body elements for example). If you have XML load it as XML. I used getNodePath() in the example to show which elements got matched. It outputs an valid Xpath expression for a given node. What you do with the nodes is up to you. See the [PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/domelement) for more information.

Comment: In fact I found the item-n tags were artifacts fruit of the several conversions I did. Upon directly reading the dictionary no such issues emerged. My present problem has thereafter become exporting the array from python to php: if I do it with print json.dumps(res) I unfortunately get error:
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 177, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <DateTime '20140128T10:00:00' at 7f82ee9a5f80> is not JSON serializable
Like if part of the output is not serializable by Json, How may I do it instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The item issue was solved. array_to_xml apparently weirdly calls the tags it generates. When directly checking the dictionary no item tag exists.